# Limiting my result set in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

So I can fill the combobox I have going in Visual Studio just how I want with ALL results with the following:

```
Dim pnum As New List(Of String) 
        For Each polnumber As InsuredDataSet.Claims_InsuredRow In Me.InsuredDataSet.Claims_Insured
         pnum.Add(polnumber.Policy_Number)     
        Next
        pnum.Reverse()

        Me.Policy_NumberComboBox.DataSource = pnum
```

Awesome.  Now I want to limit the **pnum** by taking what was input/selected from **Insured_NameTextBox** on the form and only returning the Policy_Number with a matching Insured_Name.  I figure this can be performed with an If statement, but everything I try (stringcompare, InsuredName_TextBox = Me.InsuredDataSet.ClaimsInsured, etc.) either doesn't limit the results OR limits the results entirely so nothing shows up.  Any idea where to put the If statement and what should be compared?

UPDATE:
I think there is some confusion so I'm including the entire load sub below:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'IncidentsDataSet.Claims_Incidents' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Claims_IncidentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.IncidentsDataSet.Claims_Incidents)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'InsuredDataSet.Claims_Insured' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Claims_InsuredTableAdapter.Fill(Me.InsuredDataSet.Claims_Insured)
        'textbox autocomplete mode
        Dim Iname As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
        For Each insname As InsuredDataSet.Claims_InsuredRow In Me.InsuredDataSet.Claims_Insured
            Iname.Add(insname.Insured_Name)
        Next

        Me.Insured_NameTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = Iname

        'combobox autocomplete code (now sorting by last included!)
        Dim pnum As New List(Of String)
        For Each polnumber As InsuredDataSet.Claims_InsuredRow In Me.InsuredDataSet.Claims_Insured
            pnum.Add(polnumber.Policy_Number)
        Next
        pnum.Reverse()

        Me.Policy_NumberComboBox.DataSource = pnum

    End Sub
```

Comment: What is exactly Insured_NameTextBox? A multi-line textBox?

Comment: Insured_NameTextBox is a textBox that has its own AutoComplete setup performing a SuggestAppend complete mode. It is not set as a multi-line textbox.

Comment: The question is: it is multiline or single-line. That is, how many names it is expected to contain?

Comment: It will contain one name.  In the data source the Policy_Number is the key with the Insured_Name appearing multiple times.

Comment: OK. This is all what I wanted to know; so the answers you got did the right assumption (both should work). PS: one advice (if I may): you shouldn't apologise because of not understanding C#, this is a VB.NET-tagged question and Blam shouldn't have written a C# code.

Comment: Thanks @varocarbas, I'm a database guy who's been tasked with UI for a one off, and it's super frustrating to begin with.

Comment: And varocarbas should have incorrectly stated the answers were the same as the posted code.  You need to post the current code.

Comment: @Blam I do apologise for misassuming (it looked pretty clear from the OP's words). +1 for you both as a reward for the tough, unsung battle here :). I hope that you haven't found inadequate my comment regarding C#, but this is something too common (answering with C# code a VB question) which I don't think that is right (mainly when it rarely happens inversely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Me.Policy_NumberComboBox.DataSource = InsuredDataSet.Claims_Insured.Where(Function(r) r.Insured_Name = Insured_NameTextBox.Text).Select(Function(r) r.Policy_Number).Reverse()
```

---

We're getting closer. Based on the update to your question, you're running this code when the form loads. However, at the point where the form loads, *your textbox will always be empty.* What do you do when the value in the textbox changes, to re-filter your data?

Comment: Your code delivers the same than the basic conditions the OP said that didn't work. Additionally you don't know what is Insured_NameTextBox.Text; if it is a multi-line textbox (one name per line) your code wouldn't work.

Comment: I did assume single-line textbox, but otherwise it adds the comparison his sample was missing. It's here as a starting point: hopefully the op will comment and better explain how this fails, and that will give information needed to finish the solution.

Comment: I included your code (commenting out my own from above) and I ran it, I enter an Insured_Name in the textbox and the combobox results in ALL Policy_Numbers in regular ascending order. Should I have embedded this line in the For Each statement?

Comment: @TheJ It sounds like something is over-riding this later in the process. There's no way this could return all the records unless what you enter in the boxes matches all the records.

Comment: Could it be the initial fill that mucking it up? If I comment that out, nothing shows up.  I've updated the original question with the entire code block.

Comment: The current answer to your followup question is 'nothing', as it turns out I did put the cart before the horse.  Consequently, it doesn't technically change my original question, which now should read "how do I filter the combobox based on the textbox.textchanged event?"

Comment: Alright, so I moved the original combobox code from the load sub to the TextBox_TextChanged sub I created when dblclicking the textbox in the designer.  This worked better, as on changing the textbox to a autocomplete selection, the combobox loads, albeit all selections and (still) not limiting to the contents of the textbox.  Could I just change polnumber line to read: "For Each polnumber As InsuredDataSet.Claims_InsuredRow In Me.InsuredDataSet.Claims_Insured" changing the in part to one of the variables in the textchanged "(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)"?

Comment: Figured it out.  After moving the original combobox code, I added an IF statement that matched the row pull of the FOR EACH statement to the contents of the text box.  Thanks @JoelCoehoorn.

Answer (score 1):

This is C#

```
Me.InsuredDataSet.Claims_Insured.Where(x => x.Insured_Name == Insured_NameTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: Same thing that what I said to Joel Coehoorn: you cannot be sure that you are addressing the asked problem before knowing what Insured_NameTextBox is.

Comment: @varocarbas No not the same.  See Insured_Name not ClaimsInsured

Comment: I think that your both answers are identical but I meant that you are assuming what "Insured_NameTextBox" is before the OP has explained it. In case of being a multiline textbox with various names, your solution wouldn't work.

Comment: Please don't think less of me, as I know I'm limiting my own knowledge, but I don't know the first thing about C#.  Could you convert it for me?

Comment: Just look at the VB from Joel.